# How does one use an if statement on object oriented programming (preferably in Java)?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

How does one use an if statement on object oriented programming (preferably in Java)?

```
import java.util.*;
class item 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int chance = rand.nextInt(20);
    String name;
    double price;
    {
        if (chance <= 20){
             price = price * 0.70 ;
        }
    }
}


public class tutorial{
public static void main (String[] args)
{   

    item i1 = new item();   
    item i2 = new item();

    i1.name = "Soda";
    i1.price = 5;

    i2.name = "Candy";
    i2.price = 2;



    System.out.println ("Name : " + i1.name + 
            " Price : " + i1.price );
    System.out.println ("Name : " + i2.name + 
            " Price : " + i2.price );
}
}
```

I want to:

- Create a random generator in the item class
- The random generator in the item class should effect the price in the main tutorial class
- If the chance variable is between 1 to 20 slash the price by30%
- It has to work with item 1 & 2

**Note:** I do not want to do it in the tutorial class because I will have to perform the if statement for chance fore each code. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the random generator to be the same between both variables i1 and i2?

Answer (score 2):

my psychic debugging sense says that you want your `item` class to have some sort of constructor

```
class item 
{

    static Random rand = new Random();

    String name;
    double price;

    public item(String nameIn, double priceIn)
    {

        this.name = nameIn;

        int chance = rand.nextInt(20);    
        if (chance <= 20)
        {
            this.price = priceIn * 0.70 ;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you create it in your main with

```
item i1 = new item("Soda", 5);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I may have made a syntax error, and that i'll get downvotes and comments reminding me how much better c# is than java

Answer (score 0):

First of all this method is always true due to your random settings. int chance = rand.nextInt(20); will always give you a number between 0-19, so you don't acutely need a if. You usually use if statements when you have two or more possible outcomes or certain inputs should be handled.
Let's say that you have two prices P1 and P2 for a product based on the amount of grams you buy. If it's more than 400 grams you get P2 and if it's less you get P1. An example for an if method could be like this.

```
    double p1 = 12;
    double p2 = 10;

    public double findPrice(int grams){
        double price = 0;
        if(grams >= 400){
            price = price * p2;
        } else {
            price = price * p1;
        }
        return price;
    }
```

Here you get the use of a if statement based on the value of one variable. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that I left the code as int chance = rand.nextInt(20); but I should have changed it to in chance = rand.nextInt(100); this is due to there being a 20 percent chance that the price will be effected by 30 percent off. Sorry people